# what to do when mysql command tool does not allow to enter Cyrillic alphabet?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, mysql, 17.10, cyrillic

After upgrading **Ubuntu** from 16.10 to **17.10** I have a problem.
Now the `mysql` command-line tool **does not allow to enter Cyrillic** alphabet.

When you start the `mysql` command tool, you can write SQL queries. In my query I use Cyrillic letters. When I press buttons on the keyboard or copy an SQL query from clipboard, only Latin works well. Cyrillic letters pass away. No errors! No message! Nothing. I press Cyrillic letter on keyboard and no reaction from command tool.

I made a screencast to demo this bug: https://youtu.be/0apajcBjHwU

Some configuration parameters:

```
Mysql Server version:   5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 (Ubuntu)
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
```

Output `locale -a`:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
ru_UA.utf8
```

What should I look for in this case?

Comment: You should file a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ (if this problem has not been mentioned there already) if it worked on an older version and stopped.

Comment: I just could not figure out what parameters should be collected to add an error. But the most important thing is that I needed to work. I could not wait. On a clean installation ubuntu 17.10 everything works well. Perhaps this is a very rare problem. I did not find anything on the Internet. I also arose after the upgrade from 16.10 to 17.10.  But "Ubuntu way" did not work with this upgrade. It was necessary, at first, to do 16.10 -> 17.04. And after that 17.04 -> 17.10.  I did an upgrade using "Debian way". Perhaps this was the reason. I will keep in mind your remark.

Answer (score 0):

Since this problem interfered with my work, I had to find the way out myself.
I replaced the mysql with the mariadb

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-migrate-mysql-mariadb-linux-five-steps

Everything works perfectly.